# return back(); doesn't work || Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

When try to return back and it doesn't work. Laravel tell me that page do

```html
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('koteret')
    כל המשתמשים
@endsection
@section('content')
    @if(count($allUsers)>0)
        @foreach($allUsers as $user)
            {{$user->username}}
            <?php
            $if_null = App\Follower::where('follower_id','=', $user->id)->first();
            if (is_null($if_null)){
            ?>
             <a href="{{route('following', $user->id)}}" class="btn btn-rounded btn-danger btn-sm">עקוב</a>
            <?php }
            else {?>
             <a href="profile.html" class="btn btn-rounded btn-danger btn-sm">אתה עוקב</a>
            <?php }?>
        @endforeach
    @else
        לא נמצא דבר
    @endif
@endsection
```

And there is the function

```
public function following($id) {

    $follow = New Follower;
    $follow->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $follow->follower_id = $id;
    $follow->save();

    return back();

}
```

And the route

```
Route::get('/following/{$id}','FollowingController@following')->name('following');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try one of these:

```
return back();
return redirect()->back();
return redirect()->previous();
```